# Cannot use value 0 of an enumeration while defining instances of an entity

Tags: codefluent

While using CF Entities, I'm facing an issue defining instances of an entity that uses an enumeration value.
I can add the instances of the entitytwor, but during build or save an error would show up arguing:

> CF0134: Instance value for key property 'EnumType' of entity 'Namespace.Entity' cannot be equal to the key property default value '0' of type 'System.Int32' ...

XML would present associated enumeration value for the property as expected.

It looks like the problem only occurs when first enumeration value is being used (associated value 0). Other lines won't be a problem.
Is there any particular things to do while defining enumeration values or use of them ?

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeFluent Entities defines the concept of "default value" for properties of any type, including value types and enums. The default value allows to store `null` in a database without having to use .NET Nullable type.

```
<cf:enumeration name="EmailStatus">
  <cf:enumerationValue name="Valid" /> <!-- will become NULL in the Database -->
  <cf:enumerationValue name="Invalid" />
</cf:enumeration>
```

Although the default values behavior is enabled by default you can also change it:

at the Property level by setting its `usePersistenceDefaultValue` attribute to `false`:

```
<cf:property typeName="EmailStatus" usePersistenceDefaultValue="false" />
```

at the Enumeration level by setting its `usePersistenceDefaultValue` attribute to `false`:

```
<cf:enumeration usePersistenceDefaultValue="false" />
```

at the Project level by setting its `defaultUsePersistenceDefaultValue` attribute to `false`:

```
<cf:project defaultUsePersistenceDefaultValue="false" />
```

http://blog.codefluententities.com/2012/11/15/property-default-values-and-enumerations/